# AngularJs Radio Button Dynamic Required / Not Required

Tags: angularjs

I am building a CMS which allows one to add all kinds of form fields, one of which is a radio button.

I am allowing the user to specify whether the radio button is required / not required. If its required, then user has to select a radio button, otherwise a message will be displayed.

Problem is i have been unable to get the validation to work. I.e. `data-ng-required`.

```
<div class="radio" data-ng-repeat="option in formField.options">
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             data-ng-attr-id="{{formField.fieldId}}"
             name="{{formField.fieldId}}"
             value="{{option}}"
             data-ng-model="pageForm.dynamicFormField[formField.fieldId]"
             data-ng-required={{formField.required}}>
      {{option}}
    </label>
</div>

<!-- messages -->
<span class="help-block"
      data-ng-show="_pageForm[formField.fieldId].$error.required && formSubmitted.pageForm">{{formField.labelDisplayText}} is required
</span>
```

Comment: the js controller logic would be nice to have.

Comment: Change this line : 
data-ng-required=!pageForm.dynamicFormField[formField.fieldId]

Comment: Thanks, with your hint i arrived at my answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="radio" data-ng-repeat="option in formField.options">
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
             data-ng-attr-id="{{formField.fieldId}}"
             name="{{formField.fieldId}}"
             value="{{option}}"
             data-ng-required="formField.mandatoryField === true ? !pageForm.dynamicFormField[formField.fieldId] : false"
             data-ng-model="pageForm.dynamicFormField[formField.fieldId]">
      {{option}}
    </label>
</div>

<!-- messages -->
<span class="help-block"
      data-ng-show="_pageForm[formField.fieldId].$error.required && formSubmitted.pageForm">{{formField.labelDisplayText}} is required
</span>
```